# How to activate laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

php artisan serve  Heading ##[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkWDJ.png)

php artisan serve
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The missing file shown in the error message may indicate a problem with your software installation or configuration. I would suggest you check this first. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `vendor/autoload.php` will be generated by `composer`.

Run `composer install` before you try to run your application.

If you have not installed composer yet. Follow the instructions on [this page](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

Answer (score 2):

Run `composer install` or `composer update` first before you can use `php artisan` command. The `vendor/autoload.php` will be generated by composer.